# Crystal Reports alternative that can use db connection on web.config?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

Crystal reports isn't working on different servers because they use different connection strings and crystal reports can't use the connection string stored on the web.config to access the database.

Is there an alternative to crystal reports that can use the connection string on the web.config file?

or does someone know how to fix the problem using crystal reports?

thanks.

Comment: This is really a superuser question more than a programming one.  A programmed solution using CR can set up data any way it wants.

Comment: I'm also asking how to do it, if possible, on crystal reports, which by my understanding it can't be done. you seem to know how could you please answer? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Crystal Reports API to modify the connection prior to rendering the report.

UPDATE:

[Here's](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Programming-Crystal-Reports-with-ASP-NET-2-0/3/) an example that uses the ASP.NET 2.0 CrystalReportsViewer control example in VB.NET

Comment: I it didn't seem to work... Im looking into that but anyway, how do I use a connection string name to pass the information? i have this on web.config <add name="informixConnection" connectionString="Dsn=ifxdb" /> and when I open a connection I use this line myconn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["informixConnection"].ConnectionString; How can I do something similar?